# ClearCase: Difference between delivering and rebasing

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Suppose stream B and stream C are child streams of stream A and seeded from the same baseline of A. After parallel development for a while in both B and C, B needs to obtain the codes from the latest baseline bl_C_5 of C. Is there any functional (merging of elements) or non-functional (performance etc.) difference between the following operations?

- B rebases from baseline bl_C_5 of C
- C delivers baseline bl_C_5 to B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

"`B` rebases from baseline `bl_C_5` of `C`" is impossible: a rebase can only merge baseline produced from the parent Stream `A`, not from `C`.

You could deliver `C` to `A`, set a baseline on `A` and rebase said baseline on `B`.

Then the difference with delivering directly `C` to `B` (which is possible) would be that the rebase would bring potential other changes delivered to `A`.
If no other merge (deliver/rebase) has taken place on `A`, the deliver `C` to `A`, and then rebase `B` is the same than delivering directly to `B`. The only difference is that all views on `A` would see `C` contributions.

Comment: Which brings the next question, suppose bl_C_5 is delivered from C to B. Then there is a subsequesnt baseline bl_C_6 in C. Now if bl_C_6 is delivered from C to B, will it only attempt to merge the delta from bl_C_5 to bl_C_6 in C to B?

Comment: @Raihan: not exactly. ClearCase reasons file by file, and for all directories/files modified in `bl_C_6` it will check if they need to be merged or not. The merge in itself will detect the delta all right, but that file-by-file process makes from an *incredibly* slow process (compared to a content management system like Git). For more on the merge mechanism and other characteristics:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771