# newly created baseline can't be rebased on int stream

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I created a baseline on the child stream and I delivered it to the int stream. Is it possible to rebase the stream with this newly created baseline? whenever I tried to do so, it complains that this is not the foundation baseline and it can't be rebased. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to rebase the stream with this newly created baseline

Which stream?

- You cannot rebase the Int Stream with the baseline you just created the child Stream.
  You only rebase from baselines created on the direct parent Stream, or from another project (if you rebase on the Int Stream).
- You may be able to rebase the child Stream with a baseline you create on Int Stream (after the deliver).

See more at "[Integration stream vs integration view in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880031/integration-stream-vs-integration-view-in-clearcase)".

Comment: I have an activity and I want to rebase it before deliver it. But while I do the rebase, it is saying "This stream is currently up-to-date with respect
to the project's recommended baselines.

If desired, you may select alternate baselines by
 clicking the "Advanced..." button. why this is not creating a rebase activity?

Comment: @user2370590 Is that activity on the Int Stream? Do you want to rebase it on the child stream you made the deliver in the first place? Or to another child stream?

Comment: I have an activity on the child stream of the project 1. New baseline created on the child stream but I have project 2 with the newly created baseline in the same folder. I want to see those changes in the stream of project 2 by rebasing. how should I proceed here? Should I deliver the changes to the int stream of project 1 and rebase the child stream of the project 2? Not sure if it will work.

Comment: On a different Int Stream (meaning the Int of project 2: `P2_Int`),  you can simply rebase with any baseline from project 1 (including a baseline done on a child stream). No need to deliver. That will work if you didn't create already baselines on `P2_Int` though.

Comment: @user2370590 I'll be back in a few hours. See my previous comment.

Comment: No It is not allowing me to rebase the int stream of project 2 with the baseline created on project1. Should I have to do intraproject deilvery of the baseline here?

Comment: @user2370590 no: if you deliver, it would be an interproject delivery, not an intra. An "intra-project" would be a deliver from a stream to another within the same UCM project. You need an inter-delivery, but check the delivery policies on the destination project, to check if those are authorized: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10005469/6309

Comment: I enabled the stream policy to accept inter project delivery. But I am not been able to rebase because the newly created baseline is not an ancestor of the stream's foundation baseline. Is it possible to add new baselines on the stream's foundation?

Comment: @user2370590 If you enable inter project delivery, it is to make a **deliver** between P1 stream and P2 stream, not to do a rebase.

Comment: here is the issue: I want to rebase stream so that I can see the changes made on the other stream of the project 1 to project 2.
I made some changes on stream 1 of project 1 and created a baseline now I want to take this baseline to project 2 and rebase so that I can see those changes. Is it possible here?

Comment: @user2370590 yes, it is possible... with a deliver. Not a rebase. Same as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8457833/6309): it is [a merge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12129865/6309). A rebase is always a merge between the direct parent stream and the child stream (always in the same project). A deliver is a merge between any two streams, even from different projects.